# Login screen, infinite loop and array check error

Tags: c#, silverlight, authentication, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create a login screen, that checks the user typed login and password against the stored login and password in the bi-array.

I have modified the code a few times, but can't seem to get it working.

If I put the correct login and wrong password it fails, but when I put the wrong login it, falls into an eternal loop.

Here's what I have so far:

```
string[,] loginBD = new string[9,4];    

     private void BtnLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
        loginBD[0,0] = "0";
        loginBD[0,1] = "Name";
        loginBD[0,2] = "admin";
        loginBD[0,3] = "123";
        int busca = 0,loginOK = 0, loginFail = 0;
        string login, senha;

        mID = 8;
        loginOK = 0;
        loginFail = 0;
        login = TxtLogin.Text.Trim();
        senha = PsbSenha.Password;

        do{
           if (loginBD[busca, 2].Equals(login))
           {
               if (loginBD[busca, 3].Equals(senha))
               {
                   loginOK = 1;
               }
               else
               {
                   loginFail = 0;
               }
           }
           else if (busca >= mID)
           {
               loginFail = 1;
           }
           else
           {
               busca++;
           }
       } while (loginFail == 0 && loginOK == 0);

       if (loginFail == 1)
       {
           MessageBox.Show("Fail!");
       }else if (loginOK == 1)
       {
           MessageBox.Show("OK!");
       }
}
```

Comment: Please update your title with your specific problem.. You can read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: This is a tricky one, as Login screens are very fun to make, but making a secure one is another beast.  Try not to pass your data and values (like the password) in plaintext, meaning, try to find a way to store some information (perhaps a `DataSet` or a `Database`, or both) that stores the information you wish to retrieve, then you can find how to pass the information the user has entered and Compare it against the `DataSet`.  I don't think a multidimensional array is going to be the best option, here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two problems here:

1) If your username matches (but the password doesn't), you're never incrementing your array counter (busca).  This explains your infinite loop with a correct username and wrong password.  (Have you tried debugging your code and stepping through the logic?)

2) You create your array but don't initialize all of its elements... only the first set.  Therefore, on the second iteration of your **do** loop, you're going to be attempting to call a method (Equals) on a null value - loginBD[1,3].  This will throw an exception.

Instead of initializing mID to 8, initialize it to the number of entries, minus one, in your array.  This way, the comparison of your index to the count of array items (busca >= mID) will cause the process to fail as soon as you've reached the number of actual items in the array.

Comment: Good job explaining issues without coding for him!  I wish more people did that.

Comment: thanks for your help, I just distracted myself and used "loginfail = 0" instead of "loginfail = 1". With that my project already stopped with the "infinite loop".
To check if the "loginBD [busca, 2]" is empty, I used "loginBD [busca, 2] == null" and for now everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Well the answer is quite easy. you loop the evaluation of data you entered. but when evaluation fails, you do not requery data.

You should not loop only the evaluation, but requery username and password when the authentication fails.

The raw code would look something like this:

```
private void Btn_LoginClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    loginBD[0,0] = "0";
    loginBD[0,1] = "Name";
    loginBD[0,2] = "admin";
    loginBD[0,3] = "123";
    int busca = 0,
    boolean loginOK = false;
    string login, senha;
    login = TxtLogin.Text.Trim();
    senha = PsbSenha.Password;
    //Call some method to check if the login is valid
    loginOK = checkLogin(loginBD, login, senha);
    if (loginOK)
    {
       //Do the login
    }
    else
    {
       //Clear the login-form
    }
}
```

checkLogin is meant as placeholder for the code you have in your do-while loop and should return true only if the login is OK.

```
private boolean checkLogin(string[] loginBD, string login, string senha)
{
    //Divide the amount of Array-Elements by 4 to get the amount of users
    for (int x = 0; x < loginBD.Length / 4; x++)
    {
        //you can do this in one step
        if(loginBD[x,2].Equals(login) && loginBD[x,3].Equals(senha))
        {
          //this automatically ends the loop and tells the main method that login is correct
          return true;
        }
    }
    //if there is no corresponding login in the array
    return false;
}
```

for further information on methods (if you do not know what this is) check [here](http://www.google.de/?q=methods+c%23)

as to the security of the login, you could for the time being have a look at [databases](http://www.google.de/?q=sql+databases+c%23)

Comment: Thank you for the help! Your logic seens to be a little more advanced. :) perhaps i just doesnt understand one thing...
I'm my code, i'm using a multi-array, and in your method, you put 
        
        'private boolean checkLogin(string[] loginBD, string login, string senha)'

may you explain this for me, please ?

Comment: @LucianoCaetano simply put it does return either true or false based on the stuff you put in there. this is called method. for more informations check the first like i provided. methods are one of the basic principles of advanced programming.